RTL8812au on Ubuntu 22.04.4 fails due to compiler mismatch
I am attempting re-installation of a Realtek wifi module (using the rtl8812au chip) and something has changed since the last installation.  Previously, I successfully installed it on 22.04.2 and, now, using 22.04.4 I'm receiving a message as follows:
"Warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel.

Kernel built by x86_64-Linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
You are using gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0"

The kernel is 6.5.0-41-generic.
Apart from the header on one, the versions appear to be identical.
Can anyone point me to a solution for this problem?

"Warning" messages may be ignored. "Error" messages may not be ignored.
